# Spring Batch email listener

Tags: java, spring, email, spring-batch

I want to configure Spring Batch to send an email when a job has began and also send an email when a job has finished or failed. I've seen some examples by searching such as the link here [on codecentric](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2011/09/email-sending-with-spring-batch/) but I don't use XML annotation in my project.

I have a listener that looks like this, but not sure what other pieces I may need. Any input would be appreciated

```
public class SendMailListener implements JobExecutionListener {

    final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SendMailListener.class);

    @Autowired
    private JobExplorer explorer;

    @Autowired
    private StepExecution stepExecution;

    @Override
    public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
        if (jobExecution.getStatus() == BatchStatus.COMPLETED) {
            LOGGER.info("The job has been completed with the following parameters: " + jobExecution.getJobParameters());
        }
        //send email here

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    //send email here
}
```

EDIT:

I have the job defined with the listener:

```
@Bean(name = "mccINSTANCETESTjob")
    public Job mccOrz004job(JobBuilderFactory jobFactory, //
            @Qualifier("instanceTestSetupStep") Step orz004SetupStep, //
            @Qualifier("callM204Step") Step callM204Step, //
            @Autowired SingleInstanceListener listener, @Autowired SendMailListener mailListener) { //
        return jobFactory.get("mccINSTANCETESTjob") //
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()) //
                .listener(mailListener) //
                .start(orz004SetupStep) //
                .next(callM204Step) //
                .build();
    }
```

Comment: So your question is to find workaround for XML notations. Am I right ?

Comment: Sure, or detail the components that go into sending an email from within a Spring Batch job. I was wondering if it could all be done within the listener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a bean of type `JavaMailSender` (like in the link you shared), something like:

```
@Bean
public JavaMailSender javaMailSender() {
    JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
    // set properties on javaMailSender (user, password, etc)
    return javaMailSender;
}
```

Then you can inject it in your `SendMailListener` as you did with the job explorer. Once injected, the mail sender can be used to send emails, here is an example:

```
public class SendMailListener implements JobExecutionListener {

    final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SendMailListener.class);

    @Autowired // field injection is not recommended, use constructor injection instead
    private JobExplorer explorer;
    @Autowired // field injection is not recommended, use constructor injection instead
    private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    @Autowired
    private StepExecution stepExecution;

    @Override
    public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
        if (jobExecution.getStatus() == BatchStatus.COMPLETED) {
            LOGGER.info("The job has been completed with the following parameters: " + jobExecution.getJobParameters());
        }
        //send email here
        MimeMessage message = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
        // set message properties (sender, receiver, content)
        javaMailSender.send(message);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //send email here
        MimeMessage message = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
        // set message properties (sender, receiver, content)
        javaMailSender.send(message);
    }

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Mahmoud that makes sense, except for one thing. Where would I want to define the `JavaMailSender` bean? In the `SendMailListener` class?

Comment: You would define it in you configuration class, next to your job bean.

Comment: The last thing I'm confused about is setting the properties in the configuration class, as there are no 'set' methods on `javaMailSender` , do you have to create custom methods?

Comment: That's correct, you need to use `JavaMailSenderImpl`. I updated the code example in the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, I believe that solved my problems

Comment: I'll actually have to implement this as a step rather than a listener, do you believe the implementation will change much?

Answer (score 0):

So for the workaround of XML notation you can go for job config like.

```
@Bean
public Job demoJob(){
return jobs.get("demoJob")
        .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
        .listener(new JobResultListener())
        .start(demostep())
        .build();
}
```

You can find proper article here : https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-event-listeners/

Comment: Well I understand, I already have the listener added to the job. I am trying to figure out what goes in the Listener class. I have edited my original post with more details